# The quest for 0x0B

Tags: sql-server-2005, debugging, xml-serialization

I get this error when reading some data from an SQL column  then converting it to XML:

"System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (182, 16). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: ' ', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character."

Fair enough, maybe the data is malformed. Except, how can I find the culprit row?

```
SELECT * from Mytable where Column like '%' + char(0x0B)+'%'
```

returns empty.

(obviously I attempted all %+char , char, char+% combinations, just in case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found it !

The .NET XML serializer was escaping the invalid character when serializing it, but then it was un-escaping it **before** de-serialization.

So I had to search for the **escaped** &#xB to find the un-escaped 0x0B ... seriously not funny guys!

So this:

```
  SELECT * from Mytable where Column like '%' + '&#xB' + '%'
```

Will actually find this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
      <Hashtable><key>313_other_10</key><value>&#xB</value></Hashtable>
```

And while this looks like valid XML it will throw an invalid character exception when :

```
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(Type.GetType(Hashtable));
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
    obj = xs.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

Many thanks to people who jumped in to help! It was unvaluable help!

Comment: Well, you hadn't said you were storing proper XML data in that column! That would have helped.
I'd simply though you were loading normal text content into an XML document.

Comment: so how **did** you deserialize the character?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `nchar(0x0B)` instead of `char(0x0B)` yet? As it sounds like your dodgy character is Unicode.

Comment: Good one ! Hadn't tried this yet.But it doesn't work. Still returns empty

Comment: guilty Column is nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: Wonder if it's something to do with collation. Have you tried with different COLLATE clauses?

Comment: I also think COLLATE might be the problem, but what puzzles me is that the query WILL find a 0x0B character as long as it is in the first ~100 or so characters... very unusual!

Comment: Never mind.. it will find 0x0B in any position as long as it is there. Turns out my bad row of data did not contain a 0x0B (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Character `0x0B` cannot be used in an XML document (see the list of valid XML characters [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets).) Please consider migrating invalid XML characters like this to valid XML (e.g. the sequence `&#xB;`).

Comment: Well, the vertical tab got there thanks to http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=275603

Problem now is how to find it and get it out